# How to split the data in json file using java?

Tags: java, json

I have a json file that contains lots of field which i want to seperate so that i can use it as each different field.Basically i want to split them and store them as each individual field so that i can use that file with the mysql.[image: Json File Snippet]

Comment: I am not familiar so much, but it should be an json  parser for that?

Comment: Enter code instead of screenshot.

Comment: Why post an (illegible) screenshot rather than a sample of the file? Have you tried anything or would you like us to write some free code for you?

Comment: Go to json.org.  At the bottom of the page are listed maybe 20 different kits for parsing JSON in Java.  Use one.

Comment: {"Slaves":"1","kdt build Box Gen":"0.00323034008","Job Render":"19.1420002","Adaptation Luminance":"0.00553634018","LightMan finalize PA":"6.93000004e-07","GeomMan finalize Total":"0.163755","IES bytes":"0","KDTree Kickstart":"0.0291175991","Indirect Tree

Comment: i want to seperate each field

Comment: how to use JSON parser. I Don't know. Could you please provide pointers for that

Comment: There is this thing called "Google".  Or you can use the little search line in the upper right corner of this page.  There are literally thousands of examples of parsing JSON in Java here in SO.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that this are JSONObjects line by line (no arrays). Read the file line by line and create a JSONObject with that line.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(line);
  //json.getString("Slaves");
  //json.getStrng("Job Reader");

//and so on..

//if you want to get all avilable keys.. use
    Iterator<?> keys = json.keys();

    while( keys.hasNext() ){
        String key = (String)keys.next();
        if( json.get(key) instanceof JSONObject ){
            //key = the key and json.get(key) the value.
        }
    }
}
br.close();
```

Comment: -1? wtf... for what? this is a working example matching this case.

Comment: could you please elaborate this portion particularly the commented portion of what logic shoud i use , i am novice to java:          if( json.get(key) instanceof JSONObject ){
            //key = the key and json.get(key) the value.
        }